# Earlier version associated with installed package

Tags: r, package, rstudio

Until today RStudio allowed me to build packages.  Now, when I try to update documentation, I get an error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'cli' 2.0.1 is being loaded, but >= 2.0.2 is required
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

However, the installed version of *cli* **is** 2.0.2.

First I reinstalled cli, devtools and roxygen2.  When that didn't solve the problem I uninstalled R, RStudio and all libraries, then reinstalled them, but still the problem persists.

Please, how can I solve the problem?  I just want to build packages.

Thank you

Comment: What does `.libPaths()` show?  Is the place where the new versions were installed in that list?  (You'll need to navigate there and look at install times.)

Comment: `.libPaths()` is `"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library"`.  There is only one "cli" directory there, installed about an hour ago and the DESCRIPTION says "Version: 2.0.2"

Comment: The call in the error message says that `lib.loc` was placed ahead of that in the search.  I don't know where that line of code came from, but presumably the old copy of `cli` is in whatever directory is in `lib.loc`.  Find that, and delete it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I couldn't get to the bottom of where `lib.loc` was looking.  However, I did stumble upon a fix; ... Switching off the option, "Use devtools package if available" in "Build tools" allows documentation and package creation.  

So problem seems centred on `devtools`.  I'll try reloading again, when I have time, and see if that solves things permanently.